# send-mailmessage cmdlet does not accept list variable

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I have a sharepoint list that has a people column - I am trying to write a PS script that would email a person in the people column. Now the problem I am facing is I can't substitute a list variable into the send-mailmessage cmdlet i/e the following does not work:

```
cls
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

$sourceWebURL = "http://sp2k10lab"
$sourceListName = "miztest"
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]

$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.GetItems()

$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object  {
$_name=$_['name']
$_email=$_['email']
send-mailmessage -from "support@XXXXXX" -to $_email -subject    "Regulatory Reminder Notice" -body "Tboooooooooooooooooooooooooitle is overdue by $_diff   days" -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer XXXXXXXx        
}
```

$_email is where the email address is stored in the list - however - when I try to substitute it into my send-mailmessage cmdlet it does not - the sendmail-message cmdlet works only if I explicitly set an email addy in there i.e the following works

```
    send-mailmessage -from "support@XXXXXX" -to "foo_miz <'abc@XXXXX.com'>" -subject        "Regulatory Reminder Notice" -body "Tboooooooooooooooooooooooooitle is overdue by $_diff   days" -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer XXXXXXX
```

Should I be using a different cmdlet for this purpose - or is this just me being silly with my syntax?

Thanks for any help - would really appreciate a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use the `'_'` character at the begining of your vars, just becaise `$_` is a specific var in PowerShell.

Second, here is the way I use Send-MailMessage and it works :

```
      $mailServer = "smtp.myserver.com"
      $encoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
      $cred = $null
      $body = "Are you serious !"

      $DesAdressesDest = "Nicolas S <nicolas.sc@Elyse.fs>","Francois H <francois.h@Elyse.fr>"
      $Subject = "About French bashing"

      send-mailmessage -SmtpServer $mailServer `
                       -to $DesAdressesDest `
                       -from "JP Blanc <jpb@people.com>"`
                       -subject $Subject `
                       -body $Body -BodyAsHtml `
                       -ErrorAction continue `
                       -Encoding $encoding
```